# jQuery/HTML - How do you make a space (&nbsp;) take up the same amount of space as another character when using a monospaced font?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple web page that I'm creating.

In the CSS, I am importing a specific "monospaced" font.  Everything is working great, except that the "space" character takes up slightly more space than the other characters.

The problem is that in HTML, you can only use 1 " " string in a row.  Otherwise, it obviously ignores the rest.  So in case someone types more than 1 in a row, I have to use   instead.

But, those spaces seem to take up slighting more space than the other monospaced characters.

What can I do?

Comment: try `letter-spacing: 2px;`  in the div. For space you can just use a space.

Comment: Non-breaking spaces are distinct characters. If the particular font doesn't implement a particular character, a font further down the font stack is used. I suspect the font you're using doesn't implement the non-breaking space character so the browser is grabbing the character from the browser's default font which, due to differences between fonts, may have a different width.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out!

Apparently using " " just won't work for me.

What does work is applying "white-space: pre;" to the style of div that the characters are being displayed in.

E.g.

```
<div style="white-space: pre;"></div>
```

By doing this, it will now preserve all the consecutive spaces pressed, and I can use the " " string again!  :-)

Cool.